# Python Validate Filename is of specified format or not with date part

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, filenames

I am trying to validate the filenames which are having datepart in their name. What i am trying to do is i want to check a filename with specified format where datpart is different for different file. If the filename doesn't match it should give us the message file not found.
Filename e.g =abc_sales_2020-09-01_exp.csv, abc_sales_2020-09-02_exp.csv,abc_sales_2020-09-03_exp.csv. Only the datepart changes rest remains the same.

---

```
 from datetime import date 
  def get_filename_datetime():
         return "ak_sales_" + str(date.today()) + "_abc"+".csv"
   
   name = get_filename_datetime() print("NAME", name) path = "aks/" +
   name print("PATH", path);
   
   with open(path, "r") as f:
        f.read()
```

Comment: And what is your question? Where does the code not work as expected?

Comment: the code only checks for current date part in filename i need it for different ranges of date it should be dynamice. I just need to check whether the filename is in this format or not which is aks_sales_2020-09-12_abc.csv  and in this date part is different for every filename .

Comment: please make sure the syntax & indentation is correct in your code sample. e.g. you don't need a semicolon to terminate an expression in Python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regex` to filter specific files and then open them with `pandas`:

```
import re
import glob
import pandas as pd

for file in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    r = re.findall('\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d', file)
    if r:
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Comment: Will it work for date part as well as different files have different date part i need it to run for multiple files

Comment: Please provide sample list of files

Comment: abc_sales_2020-09-01_exp.csv, abc_sales_2020-09-02_exp.csv, abc_sales_2020-09-03_exp.csv,abc_sales_2020-09-04_exp.csv. Only the datepart changes rest remains the same

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciate your help

Comment: Can you add one more change i want if the file is found to be open in a dataframe for further validation of columns

Comment: you could pass the pattern to `glob.glob`, no need for a `findall`... furthermore, this is relatively unspecific; it matches any filename that contains the pattern - which even could be something like "9999-99-99" which would not be a valid date.

Comment: the glob.glob function is finding this match also abc_sales_2020-09-02-00_exp.csv which irrelevant i just want i to look for specific file abc_sales_2020-09-02_exp.csv in which dates and exp part keeps changing and if the file matches it should open the file for further validation of columns. Can you please provide me a code snippet. Thanks a lot

Comment: @AnkitKumarSharma: see my comment above; you'll need a more specific re pattern, e.g. `r'abc_sales_[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}_exp.csv'` for this case.

Comment: @Alderven i am getting no column to parse error when i am trying to open the file while putting it into a dataframe

Comment: Also i want my date part should have dates between 2016 onwards this re expression will give me any values between 0-9 which is not correct in my case e.g it can find 67,99,34 which are not relevant datepart in my filename so can you guys please help me out in this